# Favourite questions and answers from the 2nd quarter of 2019

Tags: discussion, answers, questions

End of another quarter. So, we are back with favorite questions and answers.

Following the tradition, we would ask the community to link your favorite questions and answers created from **1st April to 30th June**.

You can search all eligible [questions](https://movies.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+created%3A2019-04..2019-06) and [answers](https://movies.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aa+created%3A2019-04..2019-06) posted in the past quarter. Since, we received 817 questions and ~1.4k answers, here are some data queries to make the decision process easier.

- [Questions with the most number of votes from the second quarter of 2019](https://data.stackexchange.com/movies/query/738289/questions-with-best-score-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2019/04/01)
- [Questions with the most number of views from the second quarter of 2019](https://data.stackexchange.com/movies/query/738288/questions-with-most-views-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2019/04/01)
- [Answers with most number of votes from the second quarter of 2019](https://data.stackexchange.com/movies/query/738290/answers-with-best-score-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2019/04/01)

The above questions and answers are only for your hint. Feel free to mention any question or answer you enjoyed reading. Since **this is not a competition**, there's no need to mention one question or answer per one answer. Also don't hesitate to mention questions and answers you posted yourself which you think didn't get the appreciation they deserved.

Answer (score 2):

First up, I really like this question made by Ankit Sharma and my answer makes it seem like the writers for GOT did have the book-readers out there in mind. [Significance of Cersei's obsession with elephants?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/98426/significance-of-cerseis-obsession-with-elephants/98429#98429)

Also, this question was really necessary and I feel like my answer was pretty concise.
[Have GoT's showrunners reacted to the poor reception of the final season?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/100777/have-gots-showrunners-reacted-to-the-poor-reception-of-the-final-season/100781#100781)

Last but not least, I loved this question about Missandei and the importance of her last words, [Why did Missandei say this?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/100359/why-did-missandei-say-this/100361#100361)

Comment: Somebody really like GoT ;)

Answer (score 2):

I really liked my own Q&A I posted on Daenerys Targaryen's final speech.

[What was the significance of Daenerys's speech to the Dothraki in S08 E06?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/101112/48608)

This answer is inspired from a Tweet I saw showing similarities at one instance. I thought of expanding the answer more. as I was searching more, I found many more references through out the show. This gave me a self satisfaction that Daenerys's turn in the final episode is not a sudden change by writers. One among many issues about the final season was answered.

Few other questions and answers are:

JJJ's question [Why did Drogon do this?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/100891/48608)

ashveli's  question [Why didn't Drogon attack this character?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/100907/48608)

TheLethalCarrot's [answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/100627/48608) to  [Is Valonqar prophecy unfulfilled?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/100621/48608)